# Magento 2 - Security Vulnerability CVE-2022-35698 - Where can I find patch for 2.4.2?

Tags: magento2, security-patch

I read about a [severe security hole in magento](https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/adobe-patches-critical-magento-xss-that-puts-sites-at-takeover-risk).

But magento does not provide a patch for 2.4.2, or I cant find it.

What should I do? How can I test if I am affected?

Comment: Update: I found this post (german) saying that there is no patch yet, but magento works on it: https://www.e-conomix.at/blog/security-updatefuer-adobe-commerce-und-magento-open-source-apsb22-48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Security Vulnerability CVE-2022-35698 does not affect in Magento 2.4.2 version. This was confirmed by Nathan Smith – Adobe Commerce Application Security Engineering Manager.

You can read more about affected version, and not affected version here: https://magetu.com/adobe-commerce-and-magento-open-source-security-hotfix-for-cve-2022-35698-and-hotfix-patches-for-2-3-7-p3-2-3-7-p4/

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing they will not include the patch for that version as its really outdated and not actively maintained.

Comment: 2.4.2 is supported until end of november 2022 though.